# How to assign list values to dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
categories =  {'player_name': None, 'player_id': None, 'season': None} 

L = ['Player 1', 'player_1', '2020']
```

How can I iterate over list and assign its values to the corresponding keys? so it would become something like:

```
{'player_name': 'Player 1', 'player_id': 'player_1, 'season': '2020'}
```

thanks

Comment: Please clarify and add a tag about what language you're using.

Comment: try to expand the data. is important to define how you iterate. The L list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If python >= 3.6, then use `zip()` + `dict()`, if < 3.6, looks dict is un-ordered, so I don't know.

**test.py**:

```
categories =  {'player_name': None, 'player_id': None, 'season': None}
L = ['Player 1', 'player_1', '2020']
print(dict(zip(categories, L)))
```

**Results:**

```
$ python3 test.py
{'player_name': 'Player 1', 'player_id': 'player_1', 'season': '2020'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat = { 'player_name' : None, 'player_id ': None, 'season' : None }
L = ['Player 1', 'player_1', 2020]

j = 0 
for i in cat.keys():
    cat[i]  =  L[j]
    j += 1
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

If the list has items in the same order as dictionary has keys i-e if player_name is the first element in the list then 'player_name' in the dictionary should come at first place

```
categories = {'player_name': None, 'player_id': None, 'season': None}
L = ['Player 1', 'player_1', '2020']

for key, value in zip(categories.keys(), L):
    categories[key] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
categories = {'name':None, 'id':None, 'season':None}
L = ['Player 1', 'player_1', '2020']

it = iter(L)
for x in it:
    categories['name'] = x
    categories['id'] = next(it)
    categories['season'] = next(it)
```